# Caculating Crc for 5 bit poly (0x15)

Tags: c#, crc

I have two CrC's I need to solve.
Polynomial length: 8 bits with an implicit 9th 1 bit
Polynomial value: 0x85
Initial Value: 0x00

and

Polynomial length: 5 bits with an implicit 6th 1 bit
Polynomial value: 0x15
Initial Value: 0x00

```
My first was very easy, with the following code. 

  byte generator = 0x85;
            byte crc = 0; /* start with 0 so first byte can be 'xored' in */

            foreach (byte currByte in bytes)
            {
                crc ^= currByte; /* XOR-in the next input byte */

                for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
                {
                    if ((crc & 0x80) != 0)
                    {
                         crc = (byte)((crc << 1) ^ generator);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        crc <<= 1;
                    }
                }
            }

            return crc;
```

but for the life of my I do not get how the 5 bit works. Of course the generator is 0x15 but that is not working in the above.  I thought maybe I run the loop 5 times instead of 8 but that is not getting it either.

example CRCs for a polynomial of 0x15.
0x80, 0x00 should get 5bit crc of 0x01

0x00, 0x20 should get 5bit crc of 0x15

0x01,0x00 should get 5bit crc of 0x16

0x01,0x20 should get 5bit crc of 0x03

0x01,0x40 should get 5bit crc of 0x09

0x01,0x60 should get 5bit crc of 0x1c

For a better understanding of how this works.There is a 2 byte memory address that steps every 32 bytes. Since the 5 extra bits are never used crc goes in them.

Example of memory address 0x0020

0000000000100000 (0x20)

Or'd crc results of 0x15

0000000000010101 (0x15)

=

0000000000110101 (0x35)

So I need to take my address of 0x0020 and get a crc 0x15 back. The Crc details are mentioned above. It is a proven Crc and used in a given application.

Per suggestion below but not getting the results I should.

```
byte generator = 0x15;
byte crc = 0; /* start with 0 so first byte can be 'xored' in */

foreach (byte currByte in bytes)
{
    crc ^= currByte; /* XOR-in the next input byte */

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        if ((crc & 0x80) != 0)
        {
             crc = (byte)((crc << 1) ^ (generator << 3));
        }
        else
        {
            crc <<= 1;
        }
    }
}
return (byte)(crc >>= 3);
```

Comment: Your second code example is not complete. What is `generator` set to?

Comment: You need to add a tag with what language you are working in.

Comment: Is says that in the OP - " Of course the generator is 0x15"

Comment: In order to look for errors, any source needs to be complete, as opposed to inferred from text. Still not there.

Comment: You need to provide more example messages and associated CRCs. Your CRC description does not match your examples.

Comment: 0x100, 0x120, etc. are not bytes. What exactly is the sequence of _bytes_ that you feed to the CRC routine to get the results you quote?

Comment: You messed up your first code example by changing it to `& 0x20`. It should have been left as `& 0x80`.

Comment: oops your right, I edited the wrong one at some point, I put it back.

Comment: And I fixed my bytes, I have that written wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `if ((crc & 0x20) != 0)`, and at the end `crc &= 0x1f;` to get rid of extraneous bits that were shifted up in the byte.

You also need to exclusive-or the data on the correct bits of the CRC.

Here is an example in C:

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdint.h>

uint8_t crc5(uint8_t crc, void const *mem, size_t len) {
    unsigned char const *data = mem;
    if (data == NULL)
        return 0;
    crc <<= 3;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        crc ^= data[i];
        for (unsigned k = 0; k < 8; k++) {
            crc = crc & 0x80 ? (crc << 1) ^ 0xa8 : crc << 1;
        }
    }
    crc >>= 3;
    return crc;
}
```

*Update:*

The OP corrected the data being used for the CRCs. It is the top 11 bits of a 16-bit address, the lower five bits of which are always zero. The 5-bit CRC then replaces those low five zeros for what is sent.

In that case, the above routine can be used to check the message, by processing the 16-bit address + CRC as two bytes. The result for a correct message will be zero. For example, this CRC of `01 7c` gives `0`.

If this 5-bit CRC is always computed on the high 11 bits of a 16-bit value, then this example will compute the 5-bit CRC and check it as well:

```
#include <stdint.h>

uint16_t crc5h(uint16_t addr, int k) {
    while (k--)
        addr = addr & 0x8000 ? (addr << 1) ^ 0xa800 : addr << 1;
    return addr >> 11;
}
```

When called with the address with the low five bits as zeros and with `k` equal to 11, the five-bit CRC to insert is returned. The address exclusive-or'ed with the resulting CRC is what to send. If that 16-bit message is fed to `crc5h()` with `k` equal to 16, all 16 bits will be processed, and the result will always be zero, if the message was received with no errors.

Comment: The code suggestion makes seance, I didn't think of removing the bits but in my attempt I run the loop only 5 times.  I think maybe I misunderstood or forgot to include some info as it always returns 1. ill show my edits above.

Comment: To process the eight bits in a byte, you run the loop eight times.

Comment: You need to exclusive-or the data in to the correct place, putting the top bit of the data on the top bit of the CRC. You can do this by shifting the CRC.

Comment: Oh, sorry c# currently not my first language. but trying to convert the code over to c# was not very effective as it has issue with bytes and casting. Also this example does not show me my polynomial. I'm terrible sorry and great ful for your help here but it unfortunately confused me.

Comment: Oh I see your example uses crc as the polynomial, I adjust my c# code above. Still not there.

Comment: I think the inline if is wrong? 
crc = crc & 0x80 ? (crc << 1) ^ 0xa8 : crc << 1;
Not following that.  crc = crc & 0x80  ^(crc << 1)?  0xa8 : crc << 1;   maybe?

Comment: Or right I was thinking your () was the condition. NM, my mistake. Ill try it out.

Comment: Can you confirm 0xa8  is the polynomial and what is passed in as crc? IS that the init value for it? 0 in my case.

Comment: Yes, 0xa8 is 0x15 shifted up three bits. According to you (not me), the initial value is zero.

Comment: ah crap, I just figured out why its not working and it was my understanding of what to send in, nothing to do with what you wrote. Its not expecting. 16 bits (2 bytes) its expecting 11 bits. If I send it a 2 bytes address shifted over 5 bits, it all works. I should have figure that maybe what is going on.

Comment: I just shifted 3 bits over before processing but yeah this would also work out nicely. Thx for all the help.